# How to add header banner in sharepoint office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

Could you share the code , as i saved my image and csv file as banner only.
But while using this snippet in script editor web part it shows nothing.

Or U may also suggest step by step procedure:

```
#s4-titlerow {
    background:#F9F9F9 url('https://flextronics365.sharepoint.com/sites/slim_/Shared%20Documents/banner.jpeg') repeat-x 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
    min-height:121px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:30px 0 0 310px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```